# mysql_insert_id always returns 0

Tags: mysql, frapi

```
  $userName = $this->getParam('userName', self::TYPE_STRING); 

  $db = Frapi_Database::getInstance();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user (userName)
            values ('".$userName."')";

  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);        

  $stmt->execute();

  $this->data['userId'] = mysql_insert_id();
```

always getting 0 in userId.

i tried to search this, but couldn't find any solution for it.

Comment: With prepare and execute calls, I think it should rather return **Fatal Error**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help guyz.
this worked for me.
$this->data['userId'] = $db->lastInsertId();

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation?

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on
>   success, **0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   value**, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

Also, these calls are deprecated.

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
>   used.

Read about choosing a new API [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: as MAMP pro has PHP version 5.4.10, i wanted to test on the older version.

Comment: and the previous insert statement makes entry in database. so connection is established.

Comment: Can you post your table's schema?